# Unable to use Tuples in PowerShell script

Tags: .net, powershell

On my local Windows 10 computer, I have this at the top of my script and it works perfectly:

```
$blackList = @(
    [System.Tuple]::Create("blacklistedEmail@domain.com","replacementEmail@domain.com")
)
```

But when I publish this to a Windows 7 machine which will actually run the script, I get

> Unable to find type [System.Tuple]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I tried adding each of these lines

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System')
Add-Type -AssemblyName System
```

But the error does not change.

How can i use tuples in this script?

Comment: I don't have a win7 machine to test with, but does it have this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx  Also, is it possible to use another type like hash table or dicitonary?

Comment: The `System` namespace is available by default. Please show the output of `$PSVersionTable` on your Windows 7 system. Most likely you still have .Net Framework version 2 or 3. The class `System.Tuple` was introduced with .Net Framework version 4.

Comment: Extactly as Ansgar Wiechers said.  You probably have *.Net version < 4* with PS 2.0 or such.  You will have to rewrite the `Tuples` into `Hash table` (with the key having a counter and value is the one from the Tuple).

Comment: Any reason why you want to use a System.Tuple instead of relying on a pure powershell solution?

Comment: @DavidBrabant Nor particularly. Is there a PowerShell equivalent which might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading `Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64` from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) and restarting the machine, my script now works fine.